# How to access instance in a function invoked by a native object?

Tags: javascript, this, instance

I admit that I've already asked a question about the `this` keyword and what it means in certain situations, but I still do not completely understand it I'm afraid. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

I basically have a Socket class, which is a wrapper to the WebSocket class of HTML5 to make things easier (I only copied what is relevant to my question):

```
var Socket = function(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.webSocket = null;
}

Socket.prototype.init = function() {
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.url);
    this.webSocket.onmessage = this.parseMessage;
};

Socket.prototype.parseMessage = function(event) {
    console.log(this); // logs the WebSocket (native) instance
}
```

In the parseMessage function, `this` refers to the instance of the native `WebSocket` object, so how can I access the instance to my `Socket` object here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `bind` it:

```
this.webSocket.onmessage = this.parseMessage.bind(this);
```

However, not all browsers support this natively, but you can grab a code snippet from [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make all browsers compatible.

In you're unfamiliar with binding ... it lets you specify specifically what `this` *should* be when that function is called. At the time that line runs, `this` is your Socket class instance, so you're basically forcing `this` *inside* parseMessage to point back to the instance.

If, for some reason, you don't want to use `bind`, another option is to save a copy of `this` to a variable so the meaning is not lost inside an event dispatch:

```
Socket.prototype.init = function() {
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.url);
    var _self = this;
    this.webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        _self.parseMessage.apply(_self, [event]);
    };
};
```

Comment: +1 on the nice answer that includes `.bind()`, but I'm wondering why you decided to use `.apply()` in this case. The simplest would seem to be `_self.parseMessage(event);`. What am I missing? :o)

Comment: @patrick dw - paranoia :) I wasn't sure if `this` would resolve to the instance or the DOM element, so when in doubt ..

Comment: Hmmm... While I can't say that I understand what you mean since in both cases `_self` will reference whatever `this` was when `init` ran, I can certainly respect *paranoia* as an general purpose motivator. :o)

Comment: @pimvdb awesome thanks. :) One more `this` doubt to scratch off my long list